# Грамматическая основа в предложении

Tags: основа

В данном предложении верно указана грамматическая основа, или нет?

**" Сидеть же полтора часа в кафе,  слушать громкую музыку и, мучась, исподтишка смотреть на чужих любовниц нимало его не прельщало"** ( Набоков)

"Не прельщало" — это же глагол? А "сидеть, слушать, смотреть" в безличном предложении дополнениями выступают?  Или тоже однокоренные глаголы?

Comment: Говоря о грамматической основе, нужно оперировать понятиями *подлежащее* и *сказуемое*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Сидеть же полтора часа в кафе, слушать громкую музыку и, мучась, исподтишка смотреть на чужих любовниц нимало его не прельщало.* ( Набоков)

*Сидеть*, *слушать*, *смотреть* - однородные подлежащие, выраженные инфинитивом.

*Не прельщало* - простое глагольное сказуемое.

Это не безличное предложение, а полное двусоставное. Все эти действия не прельщали, т.е. не возбуждали приятных ощущений.

Можно проверить себя: *Сидеть же полтора часа в кафе, слушать громкую музыку и, мучась, исподтишка смотреть на чужих любовниц - **всё это** нимало его не прельщало.*